# Reading Greenplam data from SingleStore without copying the data

Tags: greenplum, singlestore

Is there any way we can read data from Greenplam database in Singlestore database over the network without physically copying the data from Greenplum to Singlestore.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create a PXF external table using JDBC connector to Single Store and query it via Greenplum.

Comment: Can I have an example for this please

Answer (score 0):

The usql tools support 'copy' command for a lot of databases, including SingleStore and Postgres. you can try to copy from SingleStore to Greenplum directly.
I don't have Singlesotre but I have tried with mysql.

https://github.com/xo/usql